# How to read and write integer -1 into DataOutputStream

Tags: java, android, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I want to read and write some values into the DataOutputStream, 
but sometimes the value is int -1.

I am able to write this value but while reading getting EOFException, I think the value -1 its reading a EOF.

Can someone help me to figure out how can I read and write -1 into DataOutputStream.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are mistaken. Writing -1 does not cause an `EOFException` when reading. There is no problem here to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write an `int` value you can use `dos.writeInt(x)` and to read you can get `int x = dis.readInt()`  There is no way to write a value which appears to be EOF and trigger an EOFException

Comment: So, can I write many -1 values and while reading EOF will occur only once reaching the end of stream. Is that you are trying to say?

Comment: @LakshmiNaresh It is not only what he is 'trying' to say, it is what he *said*. These futile conversations about 'so you are saying' or 'what you're trying to say', or slightly rewording the answer and asking for confirmation for a slight rewordiong of the answer are just a waste time.

Answer (score 0):

to read it like int , you can:

```
 int valueInt = Integer.parseInt(readed_Value);
```